# My UIView has a UIButton as one of it's subviews but not responding to events in objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiview, uibutton

Here is my code. It has started to look crowded after an hour or 2 of trying to solve this issue. I've tried setting user interaction enabled to yes, I've tried just using a button alone and not making it the subview of another view.

**Right now I have filterBar > filterBarContainer > filterButton.**

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    self.view.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    // Create filter bar with specified dimensions
    UIView *filterBar = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 42, self.view.frame.size.width, self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height)];
    [filterBar setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];

    // Make it a subview of navigation controller
    [[[self navigationController] navigationBar] addSubview:filterBar];
    [filterBar setBackgroundColor:[[UIColor whiteColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.9f]];
    [filterBar setTag:1];

    // Reusable vars
    // CGFloat filterBarX = filterBar.frame.origin.x;
    //CGFloat filterBarY = filterBar.frame.origin.y;
    CGFloat filterBarHeight = filterBar.frame.size.height;
    CGFloat filterBarWidth = filterBar.frame.size.width;

    // Create centre filter button with specified dimensions
    UIView *filterButtonContainer = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 2, filterBarWidth / 2 - 30 , filterBarHeight - 10)];
        [filterButtonContainer setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];

    // Make it a subview of filter bar
    [filterBar addSubview:filterButtonContainer];
    [filterButtonContainer setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];

    // Centre the button
    [filterButtonContainer setCenter:[filterBar convertPoint:filterBar.center fromView:filterBar.superview]];

     // Add button to filter button
    UIButton *filterButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [filterButton setUserInteractionEnabled: YES];
    [filterButton setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0,40 , 20)];
    [filterButton setTitle:@"test" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [filterButtonContainer addSubview:filterButton];
    [filterButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor yellowColor]];
   // self.filterButton = filterButton;
    [filterButton addTarget:self action:@selector(filterButtonTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    NSLog(@"dd");
    filterButtonContainer.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
    filterButtonContainer.layer.borderWidth = 1;
```

**This is the method I'm trying to trigger.**

```
- (void)filterButtonTapped:(UIButton *)sender
{
    NSLog(@"filter button tapped");
    UIActionSheet *filterOptions = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Filter Garments"
                                                              delegate:self
                                                     cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                                destructiveButtonTitle:nil
                                                      otherButtonTitles:@"Recommended", @"What's New", @"Price - High to Low", @"Price - Low to High", nil];
    [filterOptions showInView:self.collectionView];

}
```

Comment: In filterButtonTapped Action change - replace self.collectionView with self.view i.e [filterOptions showInView:self.view];

Comment: Yep realised that was wrong so put an NSLog message to see if the action was even being fire but no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're adding `filterBar` as a subview of your `navigationBar`, but you're setting it's y-origin within `navigationBar` to 42.  And then you're setting your `filterButtonContainer`'s y-origin within the `filterBar` to 2. Assuming `navigationBar`'s height is 44, most of the `filterBar` and the entirety of your `filterButtonContainer` and `filterButton` won't be within their `navigationBar` superview so the button wouldn't be selectable.

Edit: To make it selectable while keeping the positioning intact, I suggest adding the filter bar to `self.view`. For example, change:

```
[[[self navigationController] navigationBar] addSubview:filterBar];
```

to

```
[self.view addSubview:filterBar];
```

Comment: My filterBar sits just underneath the navBar. When a user scrolls down the navBar is hidden leaving the filterBar visible.

Comment: No, you've made the filterBar a subview of your navBar so its technically within the navBar.

Comment: If you want to make it just below the navBar, add it to self.view.

Comment: Setting filterBar as a sub view of self.view makes my button work but then the filterBar doesn't move up with the navBar as it's hidden. This is why I put it inside the navBar unless theres a better way to do this? The filterBar needs to sit directly under the navbar and shift up with it when it is hidden.

Comment: As far as I know, you'll need to do this sort of animation programmatically. Whenever the navBar moves up, also move the filterBar up.

Comment: I guess I'm to used to how CSS works and was expecting this to work also. Learnt something new.. Just need to come up with a way to deal with this.

Answer (score 3):

Most likely one of your parent views (superviews of your button) have a `width` or `height` that places the filter button outside of their area. The button is still displayed (if you don't define that the view should cut off subviews), but elements outside the view's area will not get any touch events.  Check your superview's width and height.

Comment: This was the issue. I changed the origin of my filterBar to put it inside the bounds of the navBar and button is working fine. Not sure how I'm going to solve this without increasing the height of the nav bar. May have to just to take the filterBar out of the navBar and add it as a sub view of the view. Have it hidden underneath the navbar so when the nav bar is hidden and a user scrolls, it shows. However this wasn't the effect I was going for.